# How to write unit test case to set value in cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit

How to write unit test case for memoryCache.set method

```
 if(!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey,out IEnumerable<MyClass> myResult))
                {
                    myResult = await _myService.GetMyDateAsync(date, dateTo, mykey);
                    var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, myResult, cacheEntryOptions);
                }
```

Here i am checking if value exist in cache and if not exist i am calling service to get the result. Once i get response from service i am setting it in cache. Here i am not sure how to write unit test case for the Set Operation memoryCache.Set method. Can someone help me to write nunit test case to set value on cache

Comment: We need a bit more context to answer this question. For example, what type is `_memoryCache`? And do you want to write a test for the `Set` method or for the code you showed us?

Comment: You don't want to test the cache, MS guys did it well for you, and you can trust them. What you want to test here is that you are using the cache the right way. The possible test can be mocking `_myService`, then calling your code twice and verifying: 1. you got the same result on both calls, 2. `GetMyDateAsync` was called only once. If both checks are true, that means your caching logic is correct.